# Uncaught TypeError: $rootScope.$watch is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been repeatedly getting this error in my Angular.JS file. I am having trouble pinpointing exactly what is causing this error, as just last night my project was working.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

```
/**
   * @ngdoc event
   * @name $location#$locationChangeStart
   * @eventType broadcast on root scope
   * @description
   * Broadcasted before a URL will change.
   *
   * This change can be prevented by calling
   * `preventDefault` method of the event. See {@link ng.$rootScope.Scope#$on} for more
   * details about event object. Upon successful change
   * {@link ng.$location#$locationChangeSuccess $locationChangeSuccess} is fired.
   *
   * The `newState` and `oldState` parameters may be defined only in HTML5 mode and when
   * the browser supports the HTML5 History API.
   *
   * @param {Object} angularEvent Synthetic event object.
   * @param {string} newUrl New URL
   * @param {string=} oldUrl URL that was before it was changed.
   * @param {string=} newState New history state object
   * @param {string=} oldState History state object that was before it was changed.
   */

  /**
   * @ngdoc event
   * @name $location#$locationChangeSuccess
   * @eventType broadcast on root scope
   * @description
   * Broadcasted after a URL was changed.
   *
   * The `newState` and `oldState` parameters may be defined only in HTML5 mode and when
   * the browser supports the HTML5 History API.
   *
   * @param {Object} angularEvent Synthetic event object.
   * @param {string} newUrl New URL
   * @param {string=} oldUrl URL that was before it was changed.
   * @param {string=} newState New history state object
   * @param {string=} oldState History state object that was before it was changed.
   */

  this.$get = ['$rootScope', '$browser', '$sniffer', '$rootElement', '$window',
      function($rootScope, $browser, $sniffer, $rootElement, $window) {
    var $location,
        LocationMode,
        baseHref = $browser.baseHref(), // if base[href] is undefined, it defaults to ''
        initialUrl = $browser.url(),
        appBase;

    if (html5Mode.enabled) {
      if (!baseHref && html5Mode.requireBase) {
        throw $locationMinErr('nobase',
          '$location in HTML5 mode requires a <base> tag to be present!');
      }
      appBase = serverBase(initialUrl) + (baseHref || '/');
      LocationMode = $sniffer.history ? LocationHtml5Url : LocationHashbangInHtml5Url;
    } else {
      appBase = stripHash(initialUrl);
      LocationMode = LocationHashbangUrl;
    }
    var appBaseNoFile = stripFile(appBase);

    $location = new LocationMode(appBase, appBaseNoFile, '#' + hashPrefix);
    $location.$$parseLinkUrl(initialUrl, initialUrl);

    $location.$$state = $browser.state();

    var IGNORE_URI_REGEXP = /^\s*(javascript|mailto):/i;

    function setBrowserUrlWithFallback(url, replace, state) {
      var oldUrl = $location.url();
      var oldState = $location.$$state;
      try {
        $browser.url(url, replace, state);

        // Make sure $location.state() returns referentially identical (not just deeply equal)
        // state object; this makes possible quick checking if the state changed in the digest
        // loop. Checking deep equality would be too expensive.
        $location.$$state = $browser.state();
      } catch (e) {
        // Restore old values if pushState fails
        $location.url(oldUrl);
        $location.$$state = oldState;

        throw e;
      }
    }

    $rootElement.on('click', function(event) {
      var rewriteLinks = html5Mode.rewriteLinks;
      // TODO(vojta): rewrite link when opening in new tab/window (in legacy browser)
      // currently we open nice url link and redirect then

      if (!rewriteLinks || event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey || event.shiftKey || event.which === 2 || event.button === 2) return;

      var elm = jqLite(event.target);

      // traverse the DOM up to find first A tag
      while (nodeName_(elm[0]) !== 'a') {
        // ignore rewriting if no A tag (reached root element, or no parent - removed from document)
        if (elm[0] === $rootElement[0] || !(elm = elm.parent())[0]) return;
      }

      if (isString(rewriteLinks) && isUndefined(elm.attr(rewriteLinks))) return;

      var absHref = elm.prop('href');
      // get the actual href attribute - see
      // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd347148(v=vs.85).aspx
      var relHref = elm.attr('href') || elm.attr('xlink:href');

      if (isObject(absHref) && absHref.toString() === '[object SVGAnimatedString]') {
        // SVGAnimatedString.animVal should be identical to SVGAnimatedString.baseVal, unless during
        // an animation.
        absHref = urlResolve(absHref.animVal).href;
      }

      // Ignore when url is started with javascript: or mailto:
      if (IGNORE_URI_REGEXP.test(absHref)) return;

      if (absHref && !elm.attr('target') && !event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        if ($location.$$parseLinkUrl(absHref, relHref)) {
          // We do a preventDefault for all urls that are part of the angular application,
          // in html5mode and also without, so that we are able to abort navigation without
          // getting double entries in the location history.
          event.preventDefault();
          // update location manually
          if ($location.absUrl() !== $browser.url()) {
            $rootScope.$apply();
            // hack to work around FF6 bug 684208 when scenario runner clicks on links
            $window.angular['ff-684208-preventDefault'] = true;
          }
        }
      }
    });


    // rewrite hashbang url <> html5 url
    if (trimEmptyHash($location.absUrl()) !== trimEmptyHash(initialUrl)) {
      $browser.url($location.absUrl(), true);
    }

    var initializing = true;

    // update $location when $browser url changes
    $browser.onUrlChange(function(newUrl, newState) {

      if (!startsWith(newUrl, appBaseNoFile)) {
        // If we are navigating outside of the app then force a reload
        $window.location.href = newUrl;
        return;
      }

      $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
        var oldUrl = $location.absUrl();
        var oldState = $location.$$state;
        var defaultPrevented;
        newUrl = trimEmptyHash(newUrl);
        $location.$$parse(newUrl);
        $location.$$state = newState;

        defaultPrevented = $rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', newUrl, oldUrl,
            newState, oldState).defaultPrevented;

        // if the location was changed by a `$locationChangeStart` handler then stop
        // processing this location change
        if ($location.absUrl() !== newUrl) return;

        if (defaultPrevented) {
          $location.$$parse(oldUrl);
          $location.$$state = oldState;
          setBrowserUrlWithFallback(oldUrl, false, oldState);
        } else {
          initializing = false;
          afterLocationChange(oldUrl, oldState);
        }
      });
      if (!$rootScope.$$phase) $rootScope.$digest();
    });

    // update browser
    $rootScope.$watch(function $locationWatch() {
      var oldUrl = trimEmptyHash($browser.url());
      var newUrl = trimEmptyHash($location.absUrl());
      var oldState = $browser.state();
      var currentReplace = $location.$$replace;
      var urlOrStateChanged = oldUrl !== newUrl ||
        ($location.$$html5 && $sniffer.history && oldState !== $location.$$state);

      if (initializing || urlOrStateChanged) {
        initializing = false;

        $rootScope.$evalAsync(function() {
          var newUrl = $location.absUrl();
          var defaultPrevented = $rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeStart', newUrl, oldUrl,
              $location.$$state, oldState).defaultPrevented;

          // if the location was changed by a `$locationChangeStart` handler then stop
          // processing this location change
          if ($location.absUrl() !== newUrl) return;

          if (defaultPrevented) {
            $location.$$parse(oldUrl);
            $location.$$state = oldState;
          } else {
            if (urlOrStateChanged) {
              setBrowserUrlWithFallback(newUrl, currentReplace,
              oldState === $location.$$state ? null : $location.$$state);
            }
            afterLocationChange(oldUrl, oldState);
          }
        });
      }

      $location.$$replace = false;

      // we don't need to return anything because $evalAsync will make the digest loop dirty when
      // there is a change
    });

    return $location;

    function afterLocationChange(oldUrl, oldState) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast('$locationChangeSuccess', $location.absUrl(), oldUrl,
        $location.$$state, oldState);
    }
}];
}
```

Comment: Please add your full controller.

Comment: Have you injected the `$rootScope` service into the controller?

Comment: This is taken directly from the angular.js file that is added to the scripts when the AngularJS package is added to the project. I am not actually using $rootScope.$watch anywhere in my project. That is why I am baffled that it isn't working. It seems to be an error with the actual Angular code, which leads me to believe I am missing a reference or something, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Please add your full controller else we were not able to help you.

Comment: @G.Hewitson, well you have this in the posted code.
`// update browser`
`$rootScope.$watch`

Comment: Yes but the code snipet above is not code I wrote, but rather taken directly from the angular.js file

Comment: The code isnt valide. The last mustach / handlebar `}` is not needed. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: I am just trying to start up my project, but I am getting the error in the developer tools every time. It is preventing the webpage from loading.

Uncaught TypeError: $rootScope.$watch is not a function
    at $LocationProvider.$get (angular.js:14128)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4842)
    at angular.js:4636
    at getService (angular.js:4783)
    at injectionArgs (angular.js:4808)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4834)
    at angular.js:4636
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4783)
    at instantiateRoute (angular-route.js:886)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4842)

Comment: Could you try to load AngularJS by using this CDN file https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js ? Replace it with your custom AngularJS ;)